# Why does composer update --prefer-lowest produce different results depending on whether dependencies have been installed or not?

Tags: php, composer-php

### Steps required to reproduce the problem

#### 1. Create `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "knplabs/github-api": "^2.5.0",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    }
}
```

#### 2. Run the following

```
$ composer update --prefer-lowest
```

### Expected Result

Dependencies can be resolved to an installable set of packages.

### Actual Result

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1
    - knplabs/github-api 2.5.0 requires php-http/client-common ^1.3 -> satisfiable by php-http/client-common[1.3.0, 1.5.0, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2].
    - knplabs/github-api 2.6.0 requires php-http/client-common ^1.3 -> satisfiable by php-http/client-common[1.3.0, 1.5.0, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/client-common 1.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/client-common v1.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/client-common v1.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/client-common v1.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/client-common 1.3.0
    - Installation request for knplabs/github-api ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable by knplabs/github-api[2.5.0, 2.6.0].
```

### Possible Fix

I can fix the problem by running

```
$ composer install
$ composer update --prefer-lowest
```

but in the first place, why would I need to install dependencies first before being able to update them?